# Show camera image with Qt gives HIGHGUI ERROR: V4L/V4L2: VIDIOC_S_CROP

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I am trying to see camera on my qlabel, however even I cannot see it with opencv window. After I start application there is a small window created by opencv but there is no image. And in log I can see errors:

```
HIGHGUI ERROR: V4L/V4L2: VIDIOC_S_CROP

(<unknown>:7534): Gtk-WARNING **: gtk_disable_setlocale() must be called before gtk_init()
In capture... 
Corrupt JPEG data: 1 extraneous bytes before marker 0xd9
Corrupt JPEG data: 1 extraneous bytes before marker 0xd9
Corrupt JPEG data: 1 extraneous bytes before marker 0xd9
```

Here is my simple code :

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    CvCapture* capture = 0;
    cv::Mat frame, frameCopy;

    capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(CV_CAP_ANY); //0=default, -1=any camera, 1..99=your camera
    if(!capture)
    {
        qDebug() << "No camera detected";
    }   

    if( capture )
    {
        qDebug() << "In capture...";

        for(;;)
        {
            IplImage* iplImg = cvQueryFrame( capture );
            frame = iplImg;
            if( frame.empty() )
                break;
            if( iplImg->origin == IPL_ORIGIN_TL )
                frame.copyTo( frameCopy );
            else
                flip( frame, frameCopy, 0 );

            if( cv::waitKey( 10 ) >= 0 )
                break;
            cv::imshow("result", frameCopy);
        }
    }
    //    cv::waitKey(0);

    cvReleaseCapture(&capture);
    cvDestroyWindow("result");

}
```

Could you please give me idea, why I get HIGHGUI error and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting corrupted data from your camera. So jpeg decoder can not decode it. You can try to increase duration of cvWaitKey().

I hope it works for you.